# router limit bandwidth per user

Tags: router, bandwidth

I am looking at a new router to replace the one we are using at the moment.

I just need things like:

- set a max. DL/UL of 20Mbit pr. user (per IP)
- upprioritize SIP-trafic
- make sure that if many users are trying to DL/UP and in total try to use more than the total bandwith, then the actual bandwith is shared evenly on LAN (again pr. IP and not pr. flow)
- nice2have: some ways of monitoring trafik for SPAM and maybe even downprioritize or set a limit for P2P (this may be a second box).

I would like suggestions routers for:

- 100 users sharing 50Mbit fiber connection
- 2000 users sharing 1Gbit fiber connection

Could the M0n0wall do the trick?
We are using the M0n0wall at the office. Than may even be enough, but I have never heard about it beeing used with 100 to 2000 users.

I cannot set up a Linux box. I need something working more or les out-of-the-box with just some configuration through a webinterface.

BR. Anders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cisco ASA 5500?

Taken from [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/vpndevc/ps6032/ps6094/ps6120/product_data_sheet0900aecd80402e3f.html)

```
The Cisco ASA 5500 Series can support up to 10,000 simultaneous user sessions per device,
with the ability to scale to tens of thousands of simultaneous user sessions through 
integrated clustering and load-balancing capabilities. Stateful failover features deliver
high-availability services for unsurpassed uptime.
```

Comment: Thanks! Great. I am reading about it right now. This seems so to be what I am looking for. Will leave question open a bit longer to see if there are any alternative suggestions. Thanks again.